# Isometry between two $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, isometry

I have a measurable space $(X,M,\mu)$ and $\mu$ is $\sigma-$finite, then there exist a finite measure $\lambda$ s.t. the space $L^p(\mu)$ is isometric to $L^p(\lambda)$.

First I proved that there exist a function $h$ in $L(\mu)$ which is always positive. Then the problem is how to find the operator, because I can multiply for the inverse of $h(x)$, but how to define this measure? I tried $\lambda(A)= \int_{A} h(x) d\mu$ but then how can I send functions in the first space to the other?